# How to create a clicked function in tkinter calendar?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkcalendar

I am trying to create a clicked function to my calendar.

```
class MainWindow():
    
    def __init__(self, app) :
        
        #---------------------------------Initialisation de la page principale------------------------------------
        self.app = app
        self.app.title("Page Principale")

        # Center main window
       #----------------------------------------------------------------
        app_width = 800
        app_height = 600

        screnn_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
        screnn_heigth = app.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screnn_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
        y = (screnn_heigth / 2) - (app_height / 2)

        self.app.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
       #----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.app.config(background="azure")
        self.app.resizable(0,0)
        self.app.focus_force()
        
        today = datetime.date.today()
        self.cal = Calendar(app, selectmode="day", year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day, date_pattern="mm/dd/yyyy")
        self.cal.pack(ipady=20, fill="both", expand=True)        
       
        self.cal.bind('<Double-1>', self.double_click)
```

Here is my double_click function :

```
def double_click(self, event):
        print("event double click effectuer")
```

The problem is that my function is not executed
I want that when i am in the calendar, when i double click, i have the message that appear.
But only in the calendar, not in the rest of the app.
The goal is for a specific day, when the user double click, that will open a modal window with many infos of the day that he clicked
Thx for your help!

Comment: The `Calendar` widget is a frame filled/covered by labels, that's why the binding does not work because the double click event is consumed by those labels, not the calendar widget.

Comment: Okay, there is an other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Calendar` widget is a frame filled/covered by labels, that's why the binding does not work because the double click event is consumed by those labels, not the calendar widget.

Looking into the code of `tkcaender.Calendar`, instance variable `_calendar` (2D list) is used to store those labels.  So you can bind `<Double-1>` on those labels:

```py
for row in self.cal._calendar:
    for lbl in row:
        lbl.bind('<Double-1>', self.double_click)
```